# Core data: to-many relationship removing target object when removing from relationship

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

Image I have 2 Core Data entities, namely EntityA and EntityB.

EntityA has many EntityB's and EntityB belongs to one EntityA, i.e.:

```
EntityA ----- (entities) ->> EntityB
EntityB ----- (entity) ----> EntityA
```

Now image I have a `EntityA *entityA` which already has some `entities`.

Now I do the following:

```
entityA.entities = @[/* some new entityB's */];
```

Now the "old" entityB's will have a `entity` of `nil` and are thus "dangling". I want to remove these entityB's, is there an option to do so? Of course I could do it manually, but I feel like Core Data has some method of doing this automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: Calling your relationship `entities` is pretty unreadable. Maybe this is just for purposes of this example. Otherwise, please strive for concrete and logical natural language variable names.

Second: If you want to delete entities *and* sever their relationships to others, just deleting them will be enough. As you expect, Core Data does the magic for you.

Make sure your parent entity has no minimum `entities` constraint or yo will get a validation failure.

Comment: `entities` was just as an example yes. Deleting the entities itself is indeed an option, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

CoreData offers you only "delete rule" - in case you **were to delete** instance of EntityA, it could perform particular action (e.g. Cascade) to remove all of the related EntityB instances.

But your case is different - you are removing relationships between instance of EntityA and all instances of EntityB objects that were previously assigned to it. CoreDate can not determine logic behind your code - maybe you want to remove all of these EntityB instances, but maybe you want to re-assign them to different instance of EntityA later on? Or do something completely different with the "orphaned" EntityB objects?

Thus it is your responsibility to remove them manually.